# Create bitmap from byte array, which is decompressed from a JPEG file via libjpeg

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libjpeg

I used libjpeg (C library) to decompress a JPEG file. Now I have an unsigned char array. How can I create a bitmap from that array in JNI ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's [possible](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/hNapviH05Xk/jDPaxsIgodEJ), but there should be a strong justification for going this path. For best performance, use

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length);
```

Even if you need to decode the same jpeg twice - once in C, once in Java, it will save you both programming effort and execution time.

Note that Android has **libjpeg** built in (see `/system/lib` on your device), and `decodeByteArray()` uses it, and is highly optimized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the method BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length); but failed. I figured out this problem by passing a bitmap object to jni and filled values for that bitmap. It worked.